# Is it possible to use Dataverse triggers with Standard Logic Apps in VSCode?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I would like to develop Logic Apps using VSCode. Everything seems fine including the Designer, except I'd like to use Dataverse Triggers such as "When a row is modified".  I can create the connection and select my Dataverse table (e.g. Contacts). Clearly though there is no way for the trigger event to reach my local machine.

I'm essentially following these instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-visual-studio-code

There is a small mention of firewall setup, but nothing about configuring Dataverse connectors.

I tried exposing to the outside with ngrok, following this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-visual-studio-code#webhook-setup

So now instead of this:
`http://localhost:7071`

I have something like:
`https://abcxyz.ngrok-free.app`

But there's still a piece missing, how can the URL be registered so the Dataverse event can make it through to the server? Is there another way that doesn't require ngrok?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, for local development in vs code you need to use build-in webhook trigger like **When an HTTP request is received** or HTTP trigger to invoke the Dataverse REST API as mentioned in this [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-visual-studio-code#add-a-trigger-and-actions) and then you can Dataverse actions.

I am using HTTP trigger to invoke `https://******.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/WhoAmI` and getting expected result in vs code.

[image]

[image]

It is recommended to use **When a row is modified** triggers in portal.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Problem is much of our business activity centers around Dataverse business events, so I was really hoping to get Dataverse Triggers to work without having to deploy to Azure for testing.